# displays another component instead of the given component react

Tags: reactjs

I have a folder with components (App.js and Landing.js) in the index.js file I made the App.js component to be displayed, but the Landing.js component is displayed..

```
render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

Comment: Can you you share your App and Landing component code please

Comment: http://prntscr.com/26cblo3

Comment: http://prntscr.com/26cbltp

Comment: Thanks - can you include your full index.js file please (and index.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display `Landing.js` instead of `App.js` then add this :

```
render(<Landing />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

and don't forgot to import Landing Page.

Comment: I want to App.js will be displayed, and yes it is imported to index.js also, it's display Landing instead App...

Comment: Okay, then as you have sent earlier screenshot of App.js, why don't you use Layout.js in JSX

Comment: I want to understand why it's not working in this way.

Comment: Actually, your layout component is nor into App.js or index.js then how it display the layout component. You need to use Layout.js into the App.js to make display.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

File name and class and export were correct. But I did not notice that the import was specified incorrectly, therefore, for a long time I could not find the problem, I simply did not notice it.